# Traceroute in Windows PWA

Tags: windows-runtime, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to determine if it would be possible to run a traceroute in a Windows targeted PWA? I have looked into the WinRT API's (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/windows-features). Could I perhaps use the ProcessLauncher Class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.processlauncher)?

> To launch a process the .exe must either be contained in the .appx
>   package or be registered in the whitelist for this API. To add an .exe
>   to the whitelist modify
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EmbeddedMode\ProcessLauncher:AllowedExecutableFilesList
>   and add your executable to the REG_MULTI_SZ formatted string.
>
> For example:after adding reg ADD
>   "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EmbeddedMode\ProcessLauncher"
>   /f /v AllowedExecutableFilesList /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d
>   "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\0"

Would it be possible to whitelist C:\Windows\System32\TRACERT.EXE then examine the results?